# Como fazer troca de dados entre uma pagina web com App utilizando Firebase

Tags: php, java, html, android, firebase

Tenho uma pagina web onde pretendo receber informações de um App ou seja troca de informações entre eles mas utilizando Firebase, o App envia as informações para a pagina web e o utilizador responde com uma mensagem de confirmação mas tudo isso com a plataforma Firebase. 
É possível fazer a interligação entre eles utilizando Firebase?
Como posso fazer esse envio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá.
Bom, você não especificou quais tecnologias usou para desenvolver a aplicação web.
Caso esteja utilizando o angular 2, recomendo usar o AngularFire 2 (biblioteca do angular para manipulação do firebase). Mas caso a aplicação seja javascript puro, é só importar a biblioteca.
Links:
[AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2),
[Exemplo AngularFire2](https://github.com/Rafael0360/CRUD-Firebase-Ionic3),
[Como importar a biblioteca do firebase no javascript puro](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?hl=pt-br) ,
[exemplos de uso do firebase no javascript puro](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start?hl=pt-br) ,

Espero que tenha ajudado :)